# CPQ Product Rule Not to functioning with "Disable and remove"

Tags: quote, cpq, quotelineitem, product-rule

We are adding a legacy product to our org so we can track renewals, and were advised to create a Product Rule to ensure this product is only available to our grandfathered-in customers. The goal is for this product to ONLY be available for these customers at the time of renewal. It's a standalone product, and ideally, we want to completely hide/disable the product from the quote editor unless this is a quote for a legacy customer's renewal. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work and don't know where I've gone wrong.

**Configuration:**
We have a checkbox field on the Account level called "Legacy," and I created a field called "Legacy" on the Quote object, which is a formula field that pulls the value

GOAL: *If Legacy__c = FALSE, then disable/remove Legacy product from Quote Editor.*

**Product Rule:**

```
 Type: Filter
 Scope: Product
 Evaluation Event: Always
```

*I have tried changing the Type to Selection and Scope to Quote, but that does not change anything*

**Action Rule:**

```
 Type: Disable & Remove
 Product: Legacy Product
```

*I don't have any filters here, because there is nothing to update.*

**Error Condition:**

```
 Tested Object: Quote
 Tested Field: Legacy__c
 ----
 Operator: equals
 Filter Type: Value
 Filter Value: false
```

**Configuration Rules:** I have tried adding them, but this is a standalone product and there are no attributes or options. It doesn't seem to make a difference

Overall, I'm not sure if this is a misunderstanding of Product Rules and disabling/removal on my part, or if there is something missing from the configuration. Can you see where I went wrong? Or another suggestion for how to prevent this option from being selected? Any insight here would be great. Thanks!